# Twitter Fabric Login for Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I'm attempting to use the new Fabric API that Twitter is offering to let users login to my app. I've followed the tutorial exactly (at least I think I have, maybe I've made some mistakes) [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login) after setting up my project with all of the necessary steps; now when I hit the login button and authenticate the button gives back a successful response but when I go to get the Twitter Session after that I get an exception that looks like

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start Twitter Kit with Fabric.with() first
```

(again, I followed the tutorial to a T up to this point, but if you can think of anything then I'd be willing to try it)

Comment: checkout following link: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/twitter-fabric-integration/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Fabric SDK separates functionality into modules called Kits. You must indicate which kits you wish to use via Fabric.with(). This is typically done by extending Android’s Application class.

```
package com.example.app;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = 
                   new TwitterAuthConfig("consumerKey",
                                         "consumerSecret");

        Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

        // Example: multiple kits
        // Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig),
        //                  new Crashlytics());
    }
}
```

More info: https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

See the canonical sample app at: https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android

Comment: Hi Luis, could you please help me out with my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190313/making-rest-api-calls-from-an-android-app-using-twitterapiclient-class) ... thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks much! I used the Android Studio auto Fabric integration, and completely missed this little tidbit of code. I was needing to change my API Key and Secret for a client, and had no idea where to find it.

Comment: Note if you use twitter AND crashlytics, you cant have 2 different Fabric.with(...) statements. You have to chain them together: Fabric.with(...).with(...)

Comment: @Cipriani would you be able to post an updated version of your first link? It appears to be down with an "Access denied" redirect.

Answer (score 5):

My case error is: **Must start with Fabric.with() before calling twitter kit**

Solution:

Before that I have used: 
**Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());  & 
  Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));**
Finally not working.

Before Integrating Twitter my code is

--  Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

After Integrating Twitter I replace with

-- Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig),new Crashlytics());

Now working like a charm,

Comment: TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(getResources().getString(R.string.TWITTER_KEY), getResources().getString(R.string.TWITTER_SECRET));  


Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig),new Crashlytics());

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I implemented Twitter login with fabric:

1. **Declare twitter key and secret:**

   ```
    private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "r5nPFPbcDrzoJM9bIBCqyfHPK";
    private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "oJ8y2KPIySPpoBX3eCcqgcnmPGXLI94BR4g9ZztnApSmXQG9Ij ";

    //Twitter Login Button
    TwitterLoginButton twitterLoginButton;
   ```
2. **onCreate()** method:

   ```
   //Initializing TwitterAuthConfig, these two line will also added automatically while configuration we did
   TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
   Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //Initializing twitter login button
   twitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitterLogin);

   //Adding callback to the button
   twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
       @Override
       public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
           //If login succeeds passing the Calling the login method and passing Result object
           login(result);
       }

       @Override
       public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
           //If failure occurs while login handle it here
           Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
       }
   });
   ```

3.override **onActivityResult()** :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Adding the login result back to the button
        twitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

4.finally, **login()**:

```
public void login(Result<TwitterSession> result) {

//Creating a twitter session with result's data
        TwitterSession session = result.data;

        //Getting the username from session
        final String username = session.getUserName();

        //This code will fetch the profile image URL
        //Getting the account service of the user logged in
        Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService()
                .verifyCredentials(true, false, new Callback<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                        //If any error occurs handle it here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
                        //If it succeeds creating a User object from userResult.data
                        User user = userResult.data;

                        //Getting the profile image url
                        String profileImage = user.profileImageUrl.replace("_normal", "");

                        Log.d("done","name-->"+username + "url-->"+profileImage);
                       // Toast.makeText(this,"name-->"+username + "url-->"+profileImage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
    }
```

You have username and profilepicture url in `login()` to use wherever you want.

Comment: Can you tell me please how can I redirect the user to the twitter login screen (if he is not logged in) of the application if it's installed or to the browser?

Answer (score 2):

**Latest Twitter Integration with Android Studio**

This below link provide the sample code you can use this code to integrate twitter latest sdk (Fabric). it's provide all feature we can easily integrate less time take

[Twitter Sample code](https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-android)

[Reference Code Plz check it](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter)

Comment: Hello, 
I'm having some issues using the Fabric twitter login kit. From the Android Studio Farbic's plugin, at the screen of choosing an kit to install, the option is "Unknown" instead of "Install". Did anyone else encounter this issue ? 
I have to mention that with an project from scratch this does not happen.